# selecting a column values from a Table using LINQ (Entity Framework)

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Im trying to display a dropdown with values from table 'Events'. I have created a Model.edmx which has the structure of the database. Now i have to just write LINQ code to display one column values. I am kind of new to LINQ.

```
   Dim Events=" LINQ select statement part???"



    ddlEvent.DataSource = Events
    ddlEvent.DataBind()
    ddlEvent.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-Type-", ""))
```

Comment: Based on your filter conditions the query will vary. Do you filter data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropDownLists work with 2 fields:

- the **DataTextField** represents the field holding the text of the options that will be displayed to the user
- the **DataValueField** represents the field hoding the value associated with each option

So in your case, you could get it to work with something like:

```vb
Dim events As List(Of Event) =  yourDbContext.Events.ToList()

ddlEvent.DataSource = events
ddlEvent.DataTextField = "NameOfThePropertyYouWantDisplayed"
ddlEvent.DataValueField = "NameOfThePropertyYouWantAsValue"
ddlEvent.DataBind()
```

Note, however, that the query will retrieve every property from the database. This can hurt performance if your `Event` class has a lot of properties.

To avoid this, you could use the LINQ `Select` operator, used for projection. This could be used to retrieve only the necesseray data from the database. You can have a look on the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384504.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Context.Events.ToList();`

Where, Context is your EF db context. Update your filter condition in where clause

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlEvent.DataSource = from x in Context.Events select x.column;
```

here 'x' is a variable and 'column' in 'x.column' is required column you want to fetch.

Where, Context is your EF db context.